# Accidentally mounted a partition on /usr

Tags: mount, sudo, unmount

I mounted a partition on `/usr` accidentally. Hence, I have lost access to `sudo` command and can't unmount the partion. I am using AWS EC2 instance and don't have password for root user set.

What are my options? Will reboot unmount the newly mounted partition and will I get access to content of `/usr` again? Or else, how can I get root access? Are there any threat of data loss or system going to unusable state after reboot?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have the `root` account (password) enabled, you can do `su` and then `umount` the partition..

Comment: @heemayl I didn't had root account enabled. So, was out of this option. Reboot resolved the issue.

Comment: A reboot will help you (as told above). This is not a weird thing. System administrators do this to save their time (by actually not creating a new mount point).
Source: A Flickr DevOps.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes; a reboot will get rid of the mount.